# Construct parameter stack for variadic tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a class containing a variadic tuple, but need to construct the parameter stack myself. Can anyone point out to me how to do this? The tuple elements have no default constructor.

The simplified code looks like this:

```
#include <tuple>

struct base {};

template<class T>
struct elem
{
    elem(base*){}
    elem() = delete;
};

template<class... ARGS>
struct foo : base
{
    foo() : t( /* initialize all elems with this */) {}
    std::tuple<elem<ARGS>...> t;
};


int main()
{
    foo<int, double> f;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do:

```
template<class... ARGS>
struct foo : base
{
    foo() : t(elem<ARGS>(this)...) {}
    std::tuple<elem<ARGS>...> t;
};
```

Comment: Oh that was simple. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... ARGS>
struct foo : base
{
    foo() : t(get_this<ARGS>()...) {}

    template <typename>
    foo* get_this() { return this; }

    std::tuple<elem<ARGS>...> t;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e17216a1ece0689)